# How to fix pandas FutureWarning: inferring datetime64[ns] from data containing strings is deprecated

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code which worked fine until I've upgraded pandas to the latest version:

```
def group_amounts_by_batch(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
    data_frame = (
        self.data_frame[self.columns.amount]
        .groupby(
            [
                self.data_frame[ExtraColumnNames.BatchId],
                self.data_frame[ExtraColumnNames.DepositId],
                self.data_frame[ExtraColumnNames.DepositAmount],
                self.data_frame[ExtraColumnNames.DepositDate],
                self.data_frame[ExtraColumnNames.BatchDate],
                self.data_frame[ExtraColumnNames.NonFundedAmount],
            ]
        )
        .sum()
        .reset_index()
    )
    data_frame = data_frame[data_frame[ExtraColumnNames.DepositId] != ""]
    data_frame = data_frame.round(2)
    return data_frame
```

But now I'm getting the following warning:

> FutureWarning: Inferring datetime64[ns] from data containing strings is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To retain the old behavior explicitly pass Series(data, dtype={value.dtype})
> .reset_index()

How can I use the suggested solution (`explicitly pass Series(data, dtype={value.dtype}) .reset_index()`) in my code to fix that warning?

```
data_frame.dtypes:
Batch Id                    object
Deposit Id                  object
Deposit Amount              object
Deposit Date        datetime64[ns]
Batch Date          datetime64[ns]
NonFunded Amount            object
amount                     float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Where does `self.data_frame`, in particular your `DepositDate` or `BatchDate` columns come from *before* you execute this `group_amounts_by_batch` function?  In my case I had a column containing date values that were being ingested via pandas' `read_excel`. I already had a dict of converter functions so adding an additional one for the column containing date values did the trick for me. If you don't need converters otherwise and if you are using one of the read_xxx functions then using the `dtypes=...` parameters might be your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify dtype argument to your data when you create your dataframe:

```
values = [(3, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (0, 'd')]
data = np.array(values, dtype=[('col_1', 'object'), ('col_2', 'datetime64')])
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

In your case when you created your dataframe you only specified the values without the dtype!
Create your own dtype to add it in your code.

You can automate the creation of dtype using tuples, consider you have 2 lists: 1 list 'cols' for columns of dataframe and another list 'types' for column types.

```
dtype = [tuple([col, types[index]])
                    for index, col in enumerate(cols)]
```

Comment: more explicitly: `dtype = [tuple([col, df.dtypes[index]]) for index, col in enumerate(df.columns)]` and BTW this is very helpful

Comment: yes @DomenicoSpidyTamburro right, I'm glad that it's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I have got similar warning while parsing an excel file with string dates:

```py
df = pd.read_excel('path/to/file')
```

Workaround that helped me to get rid of it is following:

```py
df = pd.read_excel('path/to/file', 
                    parse_dates=['col_date1', 'col_date2', ...], 
                    date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y-%m-%d'))
```

So in your case try to wrap date columns at grouping array with pd.to_datetime() function. However, it is worth to refactor part of your code that prepares initial frame `self.data_frame` and consider proper date columns parsing there.